# "you need to load kernel first" error, I can´t find or disable secure boot in phoenix securecore setup utility

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel, windows-7, 22.04

I´m trying to install ubuntu 22.04 in a old laptop that I have, but when I try to boot it appears the menssage "you need to load the kernel first".
The notebook bios is a phoenixBIOS setup utility and has  windows 7 in it, its "brand" might be "NeoPC"...

I´ve searched a lot about this and the only solution that I found was disable secure boot, but I can´t find this option in the bios, even after  setting up a supervisor pasword.

Laptop Model: NEO A1700 Serial Number:4597901
System info: Processor Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 570 @2.26GHz 2.27GHZ
RAM: 1GB
64 bit Operational System

Some observations: I´m trying to use a USB and used Rufus to put the .iso in it. I am an really newbie at this, so I´m sorry if I said something wrong here :/

Here is some pictures of its bios and system info(but since the system info is in portuguese I writed it here too).

[System info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suh6L.jpg)
[image: Main bios]
[image: Advanced bios]
[image: Boot bios]
[image: Security bios]

Comment: Do you know if your laptop uses a 32-bit processor or a 64-bit one? You can check inside Windows 7 by going to the Control Panel and opening "System". This will show you what kind of CPU you have. If your system has a 32-bit CPU, that's your problem - Ubuntu doesn't support 32-bit systems anymore - however Debian still does. If it's a 64-bit CPU, then the problem is something else and we have some more digging to do.

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 it uses a 64-bit processor

Comment: There is a possibility that it doesn't have Secure Boot on it.  Looks possibly like your system was pre-Windows 7 or at Windows 7 which was not a requirement for that OS to work.  Is there a sticker on the bottom of your laptop showing what model it is?  Lots of systems have Phoenix BIOS on them, so we really don't have a lot to go on here.

Comment: @Terrance the model is NEO A1700

Comment: Unfortunately, I am out on this one.  Without any information about this laptop I cannot give any suggestions that you may not have already done.  Without specs I cannot confirm that you have a 64-bit CPU in your system.  You state that it is old, but some of the older laptops or tablet type systems actually had 32-bit or ARM processors in them.  You may need to get get snapshots of your BIOS setup screens to help confirm your system.\

Comment: @Terrance  sorry,  I just added the snapshots and more system info...please check it out

Comment: With 1GB of memory, you should be trying Lubuntu intstead of Ubuntu, which requires a min of 2GB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: It is an old system with the old BIOS. Secure Boot is a UEFI characteristic so it's NOT that in any case, and Ubuntu supports Secure Boot (it's just easier to disable it), so the information you got is completely wrong an unhelpful. Please follow the suggestions above or try other Linuxes because even the lightest Ubuntu flavor is now probably too much. AntiX should still work acceptably and is a modern and up-to-date distro as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you guys but I gave up of this laptop...I tried install antiX but didn´t worked too :/